# create converter for checkbox column

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, converters

I want, for a specific parameter value , the checkbox to be checked or not. 
My code:

```
 public class CheckConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object  value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string passedvalue = value.ToString();
        string parametervalue = parameter.ToString();
        if (passedvalue == parametervalue)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

And how I set:

```
checkcolumn.Binding = new Binding() { Converter = new CheckConverter() , ConverterParameter="aaa" };
```

Unfortunately, in my converter class, the if statement is always false. I don't understand why. If I have if(1==1) everything works perfect. I just want to compare the value from cell with the parameter value I give.

Comment: Have you put a break point in the `Convert` method to see what's happening? What are the two input values?

Comment: You should specify how exactly you determine the DataContext of the cell.

Comment: Yes, I put, the paramater value is set correctly . It always checks:   if(valuefromcell=="aaa"). But I can't get the value from cell. It is always false. So, I expect that object value is the value from cell , isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You should return `true` or `false` in your `Convert` method instead of `1` and `0`, cause property `IsChecked` of the `CheckBox` is of type boolean.

Also, when `value` or `parameter` is null your method will throw a `NullReferenceException`. That can also cause some problems.

Comment: yes, I know, but I use a devexpress control , and it knows that if it is 0, is false, and for other values is true. But my problem is how I compare the value from cell with the parameter value. Thank you !